# List the file and directory contents of a zip file

Tags: php

I am trying to show the file and directory contents of a zip file without extracting it. 
Zip library is not installed with PHP and I don't have permission to install it.

I am trying now to parse the output of `unzip -l <zipfile>` to get the directory structure of the zip file together with other file information. I can easily get the file information by parsing the result line by line.
However, I found it difficult to convert it a directory structure in array since I'm just a newbie in php. the structure is something like below (please ignore the syntax I'm just trying to show the structure). 
Subdirectories or sub files are placed inside the children index.

```
$file[0]['file_name'] = 'dir1',
$file[0]['children'] = array($subfile[0]['file_name'] = 'subdir1',
                 $subfile[0]['children'] = .....,
                 $subfile[1]['file_name'] = 'subdir1',
                 $subfile[1]['children'] = .....)
$file[1]['file_name'] = 'dir2',
$file[1]['children'] = array($subfile[0]['file_name'] = 'subdir1',
                 $subfile[0]['children'] = .....,
                 $subfile[1]['file_name'] = 'subdir1',
                 $subfile[1]['children'] = .....)
```

Below is the sample output of `unzip -l <zipfile>`.

```
12363  08-18-2010 13:07   lsmaps/aka.gif 
10299  03-10-2010 12:34   lsmaps/aob.gif 
26095  03-10-2010 12:34   lsmaps/cba.gif
```

Would you know of better way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pclzip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip) a pure PHP (read: you can just copy the files into your project) reader and writer for zip, like this:

```
require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
$archive = new PclZip('zipfile.zip');
var_export($archive->listContent());
```

To convert the flat information into a tree, you can use the following helper function:

```
function flatToTree($flat) {
    $res = array();
    foreach ($flat as $e) {
        $parent =& $res;
        $path = explode('/', $e['filename']);
        for ($i = 0;$i < count($path) - 1;$i++) {
            if (! array_key_exists($path[$i], $parent)) {
                $parent[$path[$i]] = array('file_name'=>$path[$i],
                                           'children'=>array());
            }
            $parent =& $parent[$path[$i]]['children'];
        }
        $basename = $path[count($path)-1];
        if ($basename != '') { // A file, not a directory
            $parent[$basename] = array('file_name' => $path[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
var_export(flatToTree($archive->listContents()));
```

Note that it uses associative arrays (or dictionary/maps) to allow faster access to the files by name. You can still iterate over it with [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). If you, however, must have numeric arrays, simply call [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) on each element.

Comment: thanks @phihag! acutally i can already parse those information. my problem is arranging the data to an array similar to the example i gave in my question.

Comment: @artsylar Extended with a helper function.

Comment: since I cannot use plugin for our source codes, I just used mine to get the zip file contents then use yours to create the array directory structure. thanks!